# Python thread Never Stops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I wrote the following simple program in python:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def handle_ip(ip_address):
    print('Child Thread')
    # Visit Web Page etc...
    sys.exit()


print('HI')
ip_addresses = ['1234']
pool = ThreadPool(processes=6)
p_results = [pool.apply_async(handle_ip, (ip,)) for ip in ip_addresses]
for result in p_results:
    result.get()
# Wait for ALL threads to finish
print('BYE')
```

For some reason it never stops running (`BYE` is never being printed), what's the problem?

I have 6 threads but only 1 is running as there is only one ip address in input, plus `sys.exit()` terminates current thread only so after it's terminated main thread should continue and end the program.

**Please Note,** I want to exit **only** the current thread, that's why I used `sys.exit()`.

My code is much more complex and this is only a simple example to show the problem (even though it doesn't make much of a sense to immediately kill the thread)

Comment: why do you use `sys.exit()`? maybe all problem is that you `exit` thread and `Pool` still waits for result from this thread. You should use `return` to exit thread. And if you don't send result then don't use `result.get()` because it may wait forever

Comment: @furas so how can I stop the thread? in my original code `handle_ip` call function `B` then function `C`, so how are you suggesting to kill the current thread inside function `C`?

Comment: @john: Why are you trying to kill the threads in the first place? Those threads aren't your code's responsibility. You're breaking the ThreadPool.

Comment: @user2357112 in some cases I face critical error regarding one single ip and I want to stop running this thread (as there is no point to keep it running - will print wrong results)

Comment: @john: That's a reason to stop a *job*, not kill a *thread*.

Comment: @user2357112 But how to stop the job if the fatal error is detected inside function that was called by another ... that was called by `handle_ip `? without doing 20 returns and without killing the whole program (with all threads)

Comment: Throw an exception, of course.

Comment: @user2357112 not in my case... most of the problematic code is already in try except. this will make a HUGE mess

Comment: It sounds like your code is already a mess. Cleaning up the mess might be a lot of work, but keeping the mess will just cause more problems.

Comment: It's just Python and its documentation. [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) promises propagation of exceptions, but apparently it means `Exception` and its derivatives. `sys.exit()` is practically a `raise SystemExit` line, and if you write that, it won't work either. However if you write other non-Exceptions (like `raise BaseException`), you will see they print a stack trace inside the thread (just `SystemExit` is special and it stays silent). If you `raise Exception` or a derivative, that will get re-raised by `get()`.

Comment: as for me killing threads in `Pool` is mistake. As I know `ThreadPool(processes=6)` at start should create 6 threads (workers) and later it will reuses them with different parameters - this way it doesn't have to create them again. If you want to kill threads then maybe you should use normal `Thread`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling pool.close() before your loop.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use concurrent?

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def handle_ip(ip_address):
    print('Child Thread')


print('HI')
ip_addresses = ['1234']

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    results = executor.map(handle_ip, ip_addresses)

print('BYE')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why this works and the OP's approach doesn't.